# Restoring pictures from formated drive

Tags: data-recovery, pictures

My hard drive was formatted, and installed new windows. I wanted to restore images so I used iCare data recovery software. Some pictures were restored, and some are restored but i can't open them. Is there any free program that can repair broken images? And also is there a better program than iCare, restoring took more then two days for 200GB drive!

Comment: If the pictures cannot be open they likely were fragmented.  This means, simply stated, the file isn't actually complete.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used **[Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)** in the past.

It's been written by Christophe Grenier (CGSecurity) who also wrote **[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)**.

With **Testdisk** you can recover lost/formatted partitions and repair/restore their MFTs (master file tables) and partition-tables.

Another great tool with a decent GUI is **[DMDE](http://dmde.com/download.html)** (DM Disk Editor and Data Recovery Software). It provides similar features and can also be used to recover **RAID** volumes.

If you're looking for a way to recover lost **TrueCrypt** partitions - **[TestCrypt](http://testcrypt.sourceforge.net/)** might be able to help.

Data recovery is slow in general and performance will vary based on the read-speed, disk-size, ...